# Why javascript can read from an expired cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var maintenanceEndDate = new Date(2018, 4, 2, 19, 0, 0);

        if (getCookie('remindMaintenanceAgain') == '') {
            setCookie('remindMaintenanceAgain', '1', maintenanceEndDate);
        }

        alert(getCookie('remindMaintenanceAgain'));
    });

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, maintenanceEndDate) {
        var expires = "expires=" + maintenanceEndDate;
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

Why the `alert` in code above still show `1` when the expire datetime of the cookie is already set to 2nd May 2018 19:00?

Why code above can read from an expired cookie?

Comment: It can't be so. I suppose that you set cookies with future date and then tried to change it. But there is condition that don't allow to set new cookies if old exists in your code. So open chrome devTools and check expires date for `remindMaintenanceAgain`.

Comment: @yrv16 I tested in IE, but I already clear all browsing history (ctrl + alt + delete) in IE before I test it.

Comment: @yrv16 I checked, in chrome, expires is `2018-5-18`. In IE (checked via code behind in visual studio debug), expires is `0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM`. Both show `1`.

Comment: 2018-5-18 is fiture date. Remove cookies in chrome and run your script again.

Comment: @yrv16 Removed in chrome, now expires in chrome is `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z`, still show `1`.

Comment: I tested your code in chrome and it's work right. It shows nothing and cookies is not set. I don't understand why you have so result.

Comment: what is your chrome version?

Comment: @yrv16 66.0.3359.170